# why isn't my variable incrementing in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, actionscript

When the user presses the space bar, I'm trying to take one string from a series of strings labeled c1-c9, break it into an array, display that array, and then increment the linenumber variable at the end of the function so that the next time the space bar is pressed, the next string in the series is traced and so on and so forth.  Here is the relevant section of script (the strings and the linenumber variable have been declared earlier)

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);

function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
        trace("okay, the key was pressed, at least")
        var displayarray:Array = this["c" + linenumber].split(" ");
        trace(displayarray);
        linenumber++;
        trace(linenumber);
    }
}
```

Every time I press the space bar, though, I just get the traces of the initial string and linenumber value repeated without any incrementing.  I think it may have something to do with the "this" before the bracket in this line

```
var displayarray:Array = this["c" + linenumber].split(" ");
```

which I found in a code sample on some website and do not understand at all, but I get compiler errors if I try to join the "c" and the line number without the "this" there.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this["x"]` is the same as `this.x`, *without* the restriction of `x` being an identifier. Thus it is `this["some dynamic property"]` (e.g. `this["c0"]` ... `this["c1"]` ...), which looks questionable but it is "valid".

Comment: The good news is: Your code looks correct.  The error is somewhere else.  Look for the part where you initialize linenumber - if that is within a frame script on a frame you loop over, it will be reset to its initial value on every iteration - and thus you always get the same value.

Comment: @pst: Why is that questionable?  It is the only way to access a property dynamically, and perfectly fine.

Comment: @weltraumpirat Because it looks like trying to access something which should be in an array: either directly or indirectly. I find needing to do dynamic properties (excepting the use in a proper Map) *rare* and thus questionable ;-)

Comment: Where and how is linenumber declared? Also, check that you are not modifying it elsewhere.

Comment: So what is the REAL question? Please focus it and take out the bit about the syntax error when changing the code. I take it that `trace(linenumber)` always outputs the same value? (e.g. 1?)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have no computer science fundamentals at all and this is my second day trying to scrape together a little art project in flash so I think it's possible that nearly everything I'm doing is questionable.

Comment: @weltraumpirat - if performance is an issue, **this.x** is more efficient than **this["x"]**.

Comment: oops, sorry, posted too fast.  Anyway, linenumber is just declared before the previously posted function as "var linenumber:Number = 1"

Comment: @pst Reading your previous statement again: You're right. The strings should be in an array, rather than in numbered variables.  However, the code is correct and should work - and this way of using dynamic properties works well if you have, for example, a bunch of movie clips on the stage and want to address them by stage name.  So to my mind, it's not really the access method itself that's questionable, but the way the strings are stored.

Comment: @SomeoneDumb That's your problem - read my first comment again.

Comment: Yes, nothing wrong in the code. if you remove all code in the function **myKeyDown**  except **linenumber++;** and **trace(linenumber);**, Your variable won't increment. Look somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced your `this` with `tempArray` and ran it.

```
var linenumber:Number = 1;
var tempArray:Array = [];
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);
for(var i=0; i<=9; i++)
{
    tempArray["c"+i]="C "+i;
}
function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
        trace("okay, the key was pressed, at least")
        var displayarray:Array = tempArray["c" + linenumber].split(" ");
        trace(displayarray);
        linenumber++;
        trace(linenumber);
    }
}
```

And this works perfectly.

One of the explanations for your code not running is
if in your code displayarray is an associative array, then trace cannot show the key-value pairs. but this doesn't explain why your linenumber doesn't increase.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to go wrong in Flash as in many other places in code or life, LOL

Try to work from the following self-contained complete as3 code. It works on my machine. Right from a clean start as3 blank project. Maybe you can adapt it to your use case ..

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);

function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    //trace(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode === Keyboard.SPACE){
        trace(lineNum);
        var dArr:Array = this['c' + lineNum].split(' ');
        trace(dArr);
        lineNum++;
    }
}

var c1 = 'a b c d e';
var c2 = 'q w e r t y';
var c3 = 'y u i o p';

var lineNum = 1;
```